# Surface Area via Polar Coordinates of Steinmetz Solid/Intersection of Two Cylinders

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have the intersection of the **solid** cylinders $y^2+z^2\leq1$ and $x^2+z^2\leq1.$ To find the surface area of this solid of intersection using the formula $$A(S)=\iint_D \sqrt{1+f_1^2+f_2^2}\space dA,$$ we consider $f(x,z)=y=\sqrt{1-z^2}$ so that $D$ is the projection of the cylinder $x^2+z^2=1$ onto the $xz$-plane i.e. $$D=\big\{(x,z):-\sqrt{1-z^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{1-z^2}, -1\leq z\leq 1\big\}.$$ Note that $f_x=0$ and $f_z=-z/\sqrt{1-z^2}\implies \sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_z^2}=1/\sqrt{1-z^2}.$ So by symmetry, the total area of the surface $A(S)$ is given by $$A(S)=4\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^\sqrt{1-z^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\space dx \space dz $$ $$=4\int_{-1}^12\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\space dz = 8 \int_{-1}^1dz = 16 $$

as expected by the formula $\text{SA}=16r^2$ for Steinmetz solids.

Now my question is how could this problem be done with polar coordinates? My first instinct was to use polar coordinates, but I struggled to get a nonzero answer so I found the above provided answer. In polar coordinates, $D$ can be described as $$D=\big\{(r,\theta):0\leq r\leq 1, 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi \big\}$$ with $dA=r\space dr\space d\theta$ and $z=r\cos\theta$ so $$A(S)=4\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-(r\cos\theta)^2}}dr\space d\theta, $$ right? However, this integral evaluates to $0.$

Comment: I don't see how. The integrand is always positive

Comment: The integral is not zero but it seems not solvable [explicitly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+r%2Fsqrt%281-%28r+cos+t%29%5E2%29+for+t%3D0+to+2pi). We usually choose the coordinates the make our life simple and that's what you did with $x,y,z\,.$